# Not allowing me to add a property to a MovieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, properties, movieclip

```
var menuButton:Array = new Array(3);    //the overarching menu buttons, these lead to a submenu

        for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            menuButton[i] = new BattleActionButton();   //creates the button

            menuButton[i].buttonID = i;
            if (i != 0) //if there is a previous button then it positions itself under it
            {
                menuButton[i].y = menuButton[i - 1].y + menuButton[i - 1].height;
            }
            else    //otherwise it positions itself under the lowest friendlyFrame
            {
                menuButton[i].y = friendlyFrame[4].y + friendlyFrame[4].height;
            }

            menuButton[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addSubMenu);

            stage.addChild(menuButton[i]);
        }
```

I'm trying to add a property to these buttons so that I can identify them later on using an EventListener, but I keep getting this error:

ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property buttonID on BattleActionButton.

at Main/createBattleGUI()

at Main()

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the buttonID property to a regular MovieClip because MovieClip is a dynamic class. If you make your class dynamic the above code will work, but it's worth noting that this is not ideal. For a simple scenario you can get away with it, but it will affect performance on a larger scale.

I recommend either adding a public buttonID property to your BattleActionButton or a private property with a buttonID getter/setter.